# Unused Business visa

Tags: visas, usa, europe

I got a 6 months business visa for the UK. But I can't use it.

My relative lives in the USA. In the future, I want to go there to meet with her.

Is there any problem getting a US visa after getting, but not using, a UK business visa?

Comment: Just to be clear, the  6-month business visa is for the UK not for the USA.

Comment: 6 months visa is for UK.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no problem whatsoever. An unused visa is not a bad thing, even less so when the countries are different.

Visa forms for US and U.K. don’t even ask you if you have ever had a visa you didn’t use.